# Hazelcast disk persistence in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am implementing Hazelcast with a Spring Boot app which is connected to a slow datalake and the requirement is the disk persistence of the cached data.
I have gone through the official Hazelcast documentation:

> https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/storage/configuring-persistence

It mainly says,

> Even after enabling Persistence, your members won’t start persisting
> any data until you configure data structures, or job snapshots to be
> persisted.

So the only way of achieving persistence is to implement a mapStore as suggested below?

> [https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/data-structures/working-with-external-data#:~:text=a%20single%20call.-,Creating%20the%20MapStore%20Implementation,-The%20following%20example](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/data-structures/working-with-external-data#:%7E:text=a%20single%20call.-,Creating%20the%20MapStore%20Implementation,-The%20following%20example)

I have already implemented below conventional Spring Boot solution to cache data (It is successfully storing data in memory)

```
@Cacheable(value = "DataByFileDate", key = "#fileDate", sync = true)
```

and Hazelcast yaml:

```
hazelcast:
  cluster-name: test
  management-center:
    enabled: true
    url: 'localhost:8080/'
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    base-dir: /path/to/persist
  network:
    join:
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        member-list:
          - member1
          - member2
  map:
    DataByFileDate:
      data-persistence:
        enabled: true
```

but, it doesn't work. Is there any solution available to achieve disk persistence through this way?

Answer (score 0):

`data-persistence` is a commercial feature. If you have a commercial agreement, you can ask for assistance on the support portal.